# Transformation of system of equations to be used in linear regression

Tags: python, math, regression, linear-regression

I have an equation that I want to transform so that I may be able use linear regression to predict D:

Equation 1: [image: formula 1]

Where βn is the first root of the equation: [image: Beta formula]

And Sh = hR/D.

Known variables = h, R, t, and y is the given dependent variable.

I have some experience with transforming linear equations for prediction using linear regression, but I am unsure if it is even possible to do so in this case given the definition of βn. Does this require a system of equations to be solved? I am aiming to implement this in python, if that adds any constraints (i.e. I cannot do it in Mathematica because it won't integrate).

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What are the ranges of D and y?

Comment: If you can write the function that calculates the value of `y` for each value of `D`, then you can build a long vector of values of `D`, use it to build the corresponding vector of values of `y`, and then you can call `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(y,D)` without transforming any equations.

Comment: y will be a number that is on (0,1), whereas D will be a fixed real number. So basically, y is dependent on time t and the Sherwood constant, where this model is trying to simply predict what D is given these other parameters.